# Dividing counts (PHP + MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

We are trying to sort through people that have purchased items to filter out people that have averaged purchasing over a certain amount of items per year.

Person 1 has bought 1.6 items/year.  We want to exclude everyone below a certain amount.  How can we do this?

```
id | item | year
1  | 1    | 2002
1  | 1    | 2003
1  | 3    | 2004
1  | 2    | 2004
2  | 2    | 2004
2  | 2    | 2003
1  | 4    | 2004
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any SQL queries and/or PHP code that you could show us? Also from the table that you have given, id = 1 has bought 11 items in total from year 2002 to 2004, which averages to 11/3. If this is wrong, how is the table meant to be interpreted?

Comment: use Double keyword to display fraction values with the average

Comment: Item is the id of the item.  So each line is one purchase.  I will add our queries and code.

Answer (score 0):

We got it. We used the query below and did the math in `PHP`.

```
$query = "SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT year), COUNT(item) from purchases GROUP BY id"
```